# Making a link unclickable while scrolling with click-and-drag

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Intro

In the code below, you'll notice that it's possible to click and drag the pictures to the left and right. However, when you release the mouse after dragging, it clicks the link under the mouse.

## What I've Tried

I've tried to use event listeners to toggle the "pointer-events" css value (element.style["pointer-events") = "none";), but that doesn't work. I'm not sure how to distinguish between a mouseup that is finishing a drag or a mouseup that is simply clicking.

## Minimum Reproducible Code

https://codepen.io/djenkins-dj/pen/WNLErLe

```js
let mouseDown = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;
const slider = document.getElementById('parent');
const product = document.querySelector('.product');
slider.style['scroll-behavior'] = 'smooth';

const startDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = true;
  slider.style['scroll-behavior'] = 'auto';
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
};

const stopDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
  slider.style['scroll-behavior'] = 'smooth';
};

const move = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!mouseDown) {
    return;
  }
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const scroll = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
};

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);

const scrollLeftBtn = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
const scrollRightBtn = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

scrollLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  slider.scrollBy({
    left: -220,
  });
});

scrollRightBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  slider.scrollBy({
    left: 220,
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.product-gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 80%;
}

.product {
  min-width: 220px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.product img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

button {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <button id="scroll-left">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="parent" class="product-gallery">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="
                hs-cta-embed hs-cta-simple-placeholder hs-cta-embed-134773165137
              " style="
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 210px;
                height: 357.390625px;
              " data-hubspot-wrapper-cta-id="134773165137">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <img alt="dog" loading="lazy" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5a/84/61/5a8461efb8ad948a89a7be973a814e4d.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button id="scroll-right">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I still want to be able to click the links when not scrolling. I'm just trying to prevent them from being clicked at the end of the drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I appreciated the solid Rick-Roll. Well done.

Second, here's the solution I found.

```
let mouseDown = false, dragging = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;
const slider = document.getElementById('parent');
const product = document.querySelectorAll('.product a');
slider.style['scroll-behavior'] = 'smooth';

const startDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = true;
  slider.style['scroll-behavior'] = 'auto';
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
};

const stopDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
  slider.style['scroll-behavior'] = 'smooth';
};

const move = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!mouseDown) {
    return;
  }
  dragging = true;
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const scroll = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
};

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);

const scrollLeftBtn = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
const scrollRightBtn = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

scrollLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  slider.scrollBy({
    left: -220,
  });
});

scrollRightBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  slider.scrollBy({
    left: 220,
  });
});

for (let i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
  product[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
      e.preventDefault();
      dragging = false;
    }
  });
}
```

I added a `dragging` variable. If the user is dragging the items, the default `<a>` event is prevented and the `dragging` state is reset. Otherwise a click will trigger the link as expected.

That was a fun one :)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I learned a couple of things from your solution (querySelectorAll & preventDefault). I appreciate the help.